# Send Data Using SocketIO from Oher Module Run by Threading

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, flask-socketio

I have a script, that look like this. And I run the the function using threading.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import threading
import time

def start_process():
    for i in range(50):
        message = "Hello, world!"
        socketio.emit('message', message)
        print(f"Event triggered! {message}")
        time.sleep(1)

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=start_process).start()
    socketio.run(app, port=1120, debug=False)
```

If using the code above, it works. But what if my `start_process` function is in another file, let's say `process_module.py`. And the script will be like this.

`process_module.py`

```py
import time

def start_process():
    for i in range(50):
        message = "Hello, world!"
        # here are command to send the message using socketio
        print(f"Event triggered! {message}")
        time.sleep(1)
```

and here are the main_script.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import threading
import time
from process_module import start_process

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=start_process).start()
    socketio.run(app, port=1120, debug=False)
```

I want to call the function `start_process` from the other module and send the message through socket using flask_socektio. I have try some methods, and it's still did not work. How to make it works?

Comment: Some clarifications you could make: what does process_module.py do?, does start_process like the example entail socketio functionality? What methods have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but here is my attempt.

your main script

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from process_module import start_process
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=start_process(socketio)).start()
    socketio.run(app, port=1120, debug=False)
```

and for process_module.py

```
import time
def start_process(socket):
    for i in range(50):
        message = "Hello, world!"
        socket.emit('message', message)
        print(f"Event triggered! {message}")
        time.sleep(1)
```

The solution was basically passing the socketio as an argument to the start_process function in an external file which we import.

Comment: I have tried to make a socketio object as the arguments for the start_process function yesterday and there was an error. But with your script, there is no error at all. Cool, thank you very much. It seems that I was not careful enough.